# Ember router issue

Tags: ember.js, routes

I created my first Ember app and have one issue with routing. I have a template that displays model for this type of route:

```
this.resource('collection', {path: '/collection/:collection_id'});
```

And the page reloads well when there is an id in the url. But I have a situation based on user interaction when collection_id is no longer available and the url becomes as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/discover/index.html#/collection/
```

But if I reload this page I get an error:

```
'Assertion failed: The URL '/collection/' did not match any routes in your application'
```

I'd like to fix that, and I think if I could capture this state and do something like this for it:

```
this.transitionTo('home');
```

that would make sense in my application. The question is how do I do this. If anybody has an idea how to accomplish this, your help is much appreciated.

My Router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource('home', {path: '/'});
        this.resource('admin', function(){
            this.route('user');
            this.route('storage');
        });
        this.resource('help');
        this.resource('collection', {path: '/collection/:collection_id'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'Assertion failed: The URL '/collection/' did not match any routes in your application'`

appears, i think, because this exact route is actually not specified in the router.

Michael Johnston`s example adding the a should work if you nest the routes like so:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('collection', function() {
        this.route('show', { path: ':collection_id' }); 
    });
});
```

The Routes for that would be

```
App.CollectionIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});

App.CollectionShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        // do the i/o for the collection here
    }
});
```

Comment: So having just this "this.resource('collection', {path: '/collection/:collection_id'});" would cause this issue?

Comment: Ember just doesn't know what to do with the URL '/collection' because you only created one for the URL '/collection/:collection_id'. You could add  `this.resource('collectionRoot', {path: '/collection'});` and create a corresponding `App.CollectionRootRoute` to tackle it as well (the naming CollectionRoot is completely arbitrary).

Answer (score 0):

This **might** work, I wasn't able to quickly test in a jsfiddle because you can't set the anchor directly:

```
App.CollectionIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('home');        
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but no changes with adding the above.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from your question:

> But I have a situation based on user interaction when collection_id is no longer available and the url becomes as follows:

The answer above (Michael Johnston) should fix your issue, but my question is why (or when) does collection_id becomes no longer available? The fact that collection_id becomes not available sound like the issue itself...

Please tell me more...

Comment: I have an input box. When the user inputs into the box the response may come with a detail for the collection_id object, but can also be related to user input and not related to  collection_id - this is when on page reload the error occurs.